# mule : Batch Processing vs For-each

Tags: mule

I have a scenario where I have a list of IDs, for each ID fetch the data from multiple API and aggregate them (this is loading phase) and then write it to DB.  I know that we can use batch processing for writing to db, but what about loading phase?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a *foreach* scope for this.

Your list of ID's will be in your payload before it reaches the *foreach*. You can use HTTP components set as *request-response*, this way all the data you need will be fetched before you reach your DB component for saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data from multiple APIs is something that takes time and has to be kept inside batch step. For each record, after fetching the data, move that to a VM queue. In the on complete phase, use a mule requester to fetch details from vm queue and insert in db. Inserting in db is a single step and does not require batch processing

Answer (score 0):

You can use scatter-gather for each id and fetch data from multiple api's. Scatter-Gather sends a request message to multiple targets concurrently.Based on the responses you can implement aggregation strategy for responses.

Similar can be done using mule batch as well.

References: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/scatter-gather